# How to filter out stuff from one column that is listed in another one?

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif

I'm attempting to filter one column from another and the formula worked at first.  Then I cleared the data and tried to reselect and now it *doesn't* work.  What's the problem?

`=FILTER(A2:A100,A2:A100=C2:C100)`

[image]

Comment: correct syntax would be `=FILTER(A2:A100,A2:A100=C2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you kinda need this:

```
=FILTER(A2:A, NOT(COUNTIF(E2:E, A2:A)))
```

[image: 0]